# Unity GetAxis Increment Calc

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to figure out how keyboard movement inputs get incremented.  For example,  I tested the values for Input.GetAxis("Vertical") in the FixedUpdate method while pushing the UpArrow. I expected to see either a fixed increase each time or some kind of weighted total.  I was wrong. Instead it appears to be totally random with the incremented amount being greater than previous amount or vice versa.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Returns the value of the virtual axis identified by axisName.
>
> The value will be in the range -1...1 for keyboard and joystick input.
>   If the axis is setup to be delta mouse movement, the mouse delta is
>   multiplied by the axis sensitivity and the range is not -1...1.
>
> This is frame-rate independent; you do not need to be concerned about
>   varying frame-rates when using this value.

That's directly from the Unity API. So it appears that button sensitivity plays a role in the output, but you should only be getting floats less than or equal to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Through much trial and error I was able to closely mimic the desired values.  I couldn't calculate it precisely but within a few hundredths per frame is close enough.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of Input.GetAxis is updated based on the following variables:

**Sensitivity:**
Speed in units per second that the the axis will move toward the target value. This is for digital devices only.

**Gravity:**
Speed in units per second that the axis falls toward neutral when no buttons are pressed.

**Dead:**
Size of the analog dead zone. All analog device values within this range result map to neutral.

Comment: I was able to mimic it exactly the help from you and Andrew.  Actually it was a simple calculation...  Time.deltaTime * Sensitivity when engaged and Time.deltaTime * Gravity when not engaged/released

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.